# Defining a view dynamically based on a table of table names

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I have a SQLite database I am routinely adding views to.  Currently I have the following tables

```
users, products, a, b, c
```

I would like to join together `a, b, and c` using a view.  However, in the future, I would like to add more tables, say `d` and `e`, to this view.  Is there a way to define a view so that it will dynamically include these new tables?  I assume I will need to maintain a table of table names that I desire to be merged into this single view, which is fine.

Comment: Create empty tables now and include them in the view statement.  When they are populated, then the data will appear.

Comment: There is an unbounded possible number of tables that will be included in the view.  Also, I will not know the name of the table prior to it being added.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in pure SQL.
(SQLite has no ability to dynamically generate SQL from SQL, and there are no triggers for table creation.)

You have to create those views in your code, when you need them.

Comment: I guess what I'll have to do when a new table is added is to fetch the schema for the current view, append a new join string, and then overwrite the existing view with the new schema.  Any thoughts on that solution?  Hacky but not sure how else to accomplish this.

Comment: There is no ALTER VIEW; use DROP and CREATE.